# Trouble to access azure containers from Azure/databricks

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-databricks, mount

I am having trouble to access Azure container from Azure/Databricks.
I follow instructions from this [tuto](https://www.sqlshack.com/accessing-azure-blob-storage-from-azure-databricks/), so I started to create my container and generate sas.
Then on a databricks notebook I delivered the following command
`dbutils.fs.mount( source = endpoint_source, mount_point = mountPoint_folder, extra_configs = {config : sas})`

where I replace `endppoint_source`, `mountPoint_folder`, `sas` by the following

```
container_name = "containertobesharedwithdatabricks"
storage_account_name = "atabricksstorageaccount"
storage_account_url = storage_account_name + ".blob.core.windows.net"  
sas = "?sv=2021-06-08&ss=bfqt&srt=o&sp=rwdlacupiytfx&se=..."
```

```
endpoint_source = "wasbs://"+ storage_account_url + "/" + container_name  
mountPoint_folder = "/mnt/projet8"
config = "fs.azure.sas."+ container_name + "."+ storage_account_url
```

but I ended with the following exception:
`shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: Container $root in account atabricksstorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net not found, and we can't create it using anoynomous credentials, and no credentials found for them in the configuration.`

I cannot figure out why databricks cannot find the root container.
Any help would be mutch appreciated. Thanks in advance.

The storage account and folder exist, as can be seen from this capture, so I am puzzled out.

[image]

Comment: Can you give the endpoint_source value in the format `wasbs://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net` and try again

Comment: As I have specified in the above comment and provided solution, the blob storage endpoint string value is not taken properly. Accept it as answer so it might help other community members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad..., I put a "/" instead of "@" between the container_name and the storage_account_url  and inverse the order, so the right synthax is:

```
endpoint_source = "wasbs://"+ container_name + "@" + storage_account_url
```

Answer (score 0):

- Using the same approach as yours, I got the same error:

[image]

- Using the following code, I was able to mount successfully. Change the endpoint_source value to the format `wasbs://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net`.

```
endpoint_source = 'wasbs://data@blb2301.blob.core.windows.net'
mp = '/mnt/repro'
config = "fs.azure.sas.data.blb2301.blob.core.windows.net"
sas = "<sas>"

dbutils.fs.mount( source = endpoint_source, mount_point = mp, extra_configs = {config : sas})
```

[image]